# Show $(-1)^n+(1/n)$ does not converge to 0

Tags: calculus

I did this by showing that $1/n$ converges to 0 by the definition of convergence. So for any $\epsilon >0$ we can find a $1/n< \epsilon$ easily since for any N we choose for $n\ge N$ then $1/n\le 1/N$ so for any $\epsilon$ we can choose some infinitely large N. So I applied to to mean that as N goes to infinity then $(-1)^n+1/n=(-1)^n$ and the definition of convergence takes the absolute value of the sequence so $|(-1)^n|=1$. So that means for any $\epsilon<1$ then there won't exists an N to make this true.

I feel like my proof has a bit of a disconnect by proving $1/n$ converges to 0 because for lower N then $1/n$ will be significant enough. Anyways I was hoping for critiques on my proof and how to make it better in order to get better at proofs.

Comment: Well, since you know that $\frac1n$ converges to $0$, if you subtract $1$ from it, it's going to converge to $-1$ (i.e. $-1^n=-1$ for any $n$).

Comment: Do you mean $-(1^n)$ or $(-1)^n$?

Comment: The idea of your proof is good but your argument's terminology is informal and/or incorrect.  If $n$ "goes to" infinity then you can't say that *is* $n$ and you certainly can not say that $(-1)^n + \frac 1n = (-1)^n$.  $\frac 1n \ne 0$.  $\lim \frac 1n = 0$ and *IF* $\lim (-1)^n$ existed (which it does *not*) then $\lim (-1)^n + \frac 1n = \lim(-1)^n$ but it *DOESN"T* exist.  But you can do a prove by contradiction. If $\lim (-1)^n + \frac 1n =0$ then $\lim \frac (-1)^n = \lim [((-1)^n + \frac n) - \frac 1n] =\lim ((-1)^n + \frac n)  - \lim \frac 1n = 0 - 0=0$ bu $\lim (-1)^n\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$u_n=(-1)^n$$

then

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}u_{2n}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}1=1$$
but

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}u_{2n+1}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}(-1)=-1$$

thus
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(-1)^n \text{ does not exist}$$
and

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}((-1)^n+\frac 1n)$$
doesn't exist and consequently is $\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the definition of convergence.

Assuming by contradiction that $(-1)^n + \frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that if $n \ge N$ then $\left| \left((-1)^n + \frac{1}{n}\right) - 0 \right| < \epsilon$.

Since this is true for any $\epsilon$, it's true for $\epsilon = \frac{1}{10}$. So we may choose $N$ such that if $n \ge N$ then $\left|(-1)^n + \frac{1}{n} \right| < \frac{1}{10}$. But 
$$\left|(-1)^n + \frac{1}{n} \right| \ge \left| 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right| = 1 - \frac{1}{n}
$$
It follows that if $n \ge N$ then $1 - \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{10}$. But that's ridiculous, I can simply choose $n = \text{max}\{N,20\}$, and it would follow that $1 - \frac{1}{n} \ge 1 - \frac{1}{20} = \frac{19}{10}$, and so $\frac{19}{20} < \frac{1}{10}$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Good idea. More simply, you have $\left| (-1)^n+\frac{1}{n} \right| \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$ for any $n\geqslant 2$.

Comment: Very creative solution.

Answer (score 0):

It does not converge at all since
$(-1)^{2n} = 1$
and
$(-1)^{2n+1} = -1$
and
$\dfrac1{n} \to 0$.